# How to remove backgound white when horizontal line with words in the middle

Tags: html, css

Please tell me how to remove background white color and worked horizontal line with words in the middle with css.

This is my code please check.

```css
.asses {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7d9eb;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.asses span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-family: 'lato';
    color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="asses">
    <span>My TEXT HERE</span>
</h2>
```

So now please tell me how to solve that issue

Comment: What are you asking? it seems that your code works..

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: yes it's worked because in this text background color white but i didn't want white because in my website backgound image is colorful that's why is this any trick to transparent and run like that. Thanks

Comment: if you want to remove the background color then you have to use before after and give width them accordingly.

Comment: check all the answer of the duplicate, not only the accpeted one especially the second one

Comment: @Chilll007 will please make code over my code please thanks

Comment: your answer is marked as duplicate so cant answer your question you can https://jsfiddle.net/y9qg6d04/ use this as referance.

Comment: yes your comment is really worked thanks @Chilll007

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
h2 {
  font: 33px sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


h2.asses {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2.asses span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

h2.asses span:before,
h2.asses span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.73em;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

h2.asses span:before {
  right: 100%;
}

h2.asses span:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="asses"><span>My TEXT HERE</span></h2>
```

Refer this link [Line behind text](https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm?editors=0100) for more examples

Comment: Yeah this is i want will you please make this on my code please thanks

Comment: Your code is really awesome please make this on code. thanks

Comment: @ahhh , check the code now

Comment: @ahhh  if its working for u, then accept my answer